# Change customer name through batch in Parallels Plesk

Tags: windows, batch-file, plesk, parallels

I am trying to change the cname through a batch.. It is successfully done for English language but I want to use Arabic language. When I am using Arabic it appear like this "????".

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the code page is wrong. Add the line `chcp 1256` to your batch file for Arabic character support.